# 1 :: List[Nothing] in foldLeft

Tags: scala, haskell, generics

If:

```
scala> val l = List()      // List() same as List[Nothing]()
l: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> 1 :: l
res0: List[Int] = List(1)
```

or:

```
scala> 1 :: List[Nothing]()
res6: List[Int] = List(1)
```

Why then this does not work out:

```
scala> List(1,2,3). foldLeft( List() ) ((acc,x) => x :: acc)
```

So I have to type this explicitly `List[Int]()`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3). foldLeft( List[Int]() ) ((acc,x) => x :: acc)
res3: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

?

Though it does in Haskell, for example:

```
 foldl (\acc x -> x:acc) [] [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at scala's foldLeft signature:

```
List[+A].foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

and haskell's signature:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

They pretty much same, but:

1) scala has problem with type inference between [pseudo-]curried parameter lists, just compare:

```
 scala> def aaa[A](a: A)(b: A) = {}
 aaa: [A](a: A)(b: A)Unit

 scala> aaa(null: Any)(5)

 scala> aaa(5)(null: Any)
 <console>:21: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Any
  required: Int
              aaa(5)(null: Any)
                         ^
```

So scala can choose bigger type from left to right only.

More than that, this is a problem only for [pseudo-]curried functions:

```
scala> def aaa[T](a: T, b: T) = a
aaa: [T](a: T, b: T)T

scala> aaa(List("a"), List(6.0))
res26: List[Any] = List(a)

scala> aaa(List(6.0), List("a"))
res27: List[Any] = List(6.0)
```

Here scala not only picked a bigger type - it  found a common supertype of both `T`'s. So, it's trying to choose bigger type (if it's in the left part) by default, but looking for a common supertype inside one parameter list.

Note: I'm talking about [pseudo-] currying, as method with multiple parameter lists `(B)((B, A) => B)B` becoming curried function only after eta-expansion: `foldLeft _` gives `B => (B,A) => B`

2) haskell uses "object" of `List` itself as function's parameter, which allows you to do even:

```
 Prelude> let f = foldl (\acc x -> x:acc) [] 
 :: [a] -> [a] //here is the polymorphic function
 Prelude> f [1,2,3]
 [3,2,1]
 Prelude> f ["1","2","3"]
 ["3","2","1"]
```

In scala you need:

```
 scala> def f[T](x: List[T]) = x.foldLeft(List[T]()) ((acc,x) => x :: acc)
 f: [T](x: List[T])List[T]

 scala> f(List(1,2,3))
 res3: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)

 scala> f(List("1","2","3"))
 res3: List[String] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

3) Finally, let's rewrite `foldLeft` and place monoid's 'add' and 'identity' to the same parameter list (to avoid separate inference from p.1):

```
 def foldLeft[T, U](l: List[T])(identity: U, add: (U,T) => U) = l.foldLeft(identity)(add)
```

and define polymorphic `add` operation:

```
 scala> def add[A](x: List[A], y: A) = y :: x
 add: [A](x: List[A], y: A)List[A]
```

So you can:

```
scala> foldLeft(List(1,2,3))(Nil, add)
res63: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

in comparision with:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(Nil)(add)
 <console>:9: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  found   : [A, B](x: List[A], y: A)List[A]
  required: (scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type, Int) => scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
          List(1,2,3).foldLeft(Nil)(add)
                                    ^
```

Unfortunately, scala can't infer generic type for lambdas, so you can't:

```
scala> foldLeft(List(1,2,3))(Nil, (acc,x) => x :: acc)
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
          foldLeft(List(1,2,3))(Nil, (acc,x) => x :: acc)
```

as you can't:

```
scala> val a = (acc,x) => x :: acc
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type
   val a = (acc,x) => x :: acc
            ^
```

2 & 3) Because scala has **no polymorphic lambdas** at all. Can't infer `A => List[A] => A` (where A is a type parameter) from `(acc,x) => x :: acc` (even `A => A` from `val a = (a) => a`), but Haskell can:

```
Prelude> let lambda = \acc x -> x:acc
:: [a] -> a -> [a]
Prelude> let f = foldl(lambda) []
Prelude> f [1,2,3]
[3,2,1]
```

Here is an eta-expansion of perviously defined `add` generic method in scala:

```
scala> add _
res2: (List[Nothing], Nothing) => List[Nothing] = <function2>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

`Nothing` is a sub-type of every other type, in this case `Int`. Since `List()` is inferred to have type `List[Nothing]`, then `f` is expected to be `(List[Nothing], A) => List[Nothing]`

But in the function `(acc, x) => x :: acc)` , `A` is an `Int`, which means you should have:

```
(List[Nothing], Int) => List[Nothing]
```

When really you have:

```
(List[Nothing], Int) => List[Int]
```

And thus the type mismatch, because `List[Int]` can't be a `List[Nothing]`.

This is similar to:

```
class A
class B extends A

scala> List.fill(5)(new A).foldLeft(List.empty[B])((acc, x) => x :: acc)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: B
          List.fill(5)(new A).foldLeft(List.empty[B])((acc, x) => x :: acc)
                                                                    ^
```

Comment: not true: `def foldLeft[T, U](l: List[T])(identity: U, f: (U,T) => U) = l.foldLeft(identity)(f)` works fine - it's just a problem with scala's type inference and currying

Comment: simplified example: `def aaa(x: List[Nothing]) = 5 :: x` results in `aaa: (x: List[Nothing])List[Int]`

Comment: Just because it's a problem with type inference doesn't make my answer any less true. I'm explaining the source of the type mismatch. Your simplified example is irrelevant to my explanation. Furthermore, your `foldLeft` still requires explicit type annotations on the folding function. The point is, the inferred `List[Nothing]` on `B` leads to the type mismatch.

Comment: :) see my answer's update for explanation about lambda's problem (if it's interesting). Lambda's in Haskell can accept type parameters, so you can write an analog of `val a = (acc, x) => x :: acc` , so it will be `List[A] => A => List[A]` - my example works with generic lists (if they explicitly mentioned in function definition instead of lambda) - just doesn't work with scala's lambdas

Comment: So my example isn't equivalent with `.empty[Int]` as i still don't have to specify `Int` explicitly. Actually, the source of type mismatch here is poor type inference.