# Scala Fold Function Mismatch type

Tags: scala, scaffolding, folding

I have a `FoldSignal` case class as following.

```
/**
 * Represents a signal that is manipulated to using the functional "fold" operation
 * @param s Underlying signal
 * @param start seed for the fold
 * @param f fold function
 */
 case class FoldSignal[T, U](s: Signal[T], start: U, f: (U, T) => U) extends Signal[U]
```

And I used it to create a function in Signal[T]:

```
sealed trait Signal[T]{
 ...

/**
 * Return a delta of signals in windows
 */
 def delta(implicit ev: T =:= (_, DateTime) ): Signal[T] = {
   def foldFun(queue: List[T], t: T) = {
     println(queue(0))
     queue(0)._1
   }
   FoldSignal(this, Nil, foldFun)
 }
 ...
}
```

where Signal[T] is a sealed trait:

```
/**
 * Signal is a AST object represents a value that is continuously emitted. It does
 * not specify anything about the source of the signal.
 */
sealed trait Signal[T] {...}
```

And it comes up an error:

```
Error:(71, 22) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: T
    FoldSignal(this, Nil, foldFun)
                 ^
```

Could someone help me, please! Thanks!

Comment: The error message of function foldFun is `Expression of type FoldSignal[T, Any] doesn't conform to expected type Signal[T]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up types with your `(_, DateTime)` - your `foldFun` should return `U` (see `f: (U, T) => U`) which is `List[T]` but you return `U.head._1` which is `Any` (as a result of resolving of your existential type `_`)

---

You see what you see because Scala can't infer a type (for `Nil`) here (type inference doesn't see connection between `f` and `start` parameters), try:

```
 FoldSignal(this, List.empty[T], foldFun)
```

Another approach is to to separate `f` and `start` into different parameter lists (`start` should be first - so `T` is gonna be inferred first from it):

```
def makeFoldSignal[T, U](s: Signal[T], f: (U, T) => U)(start: U)
```

May be related and explains about type inference a bit (in comparison with Haskell): [1 :: List[Nothing] in foldLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652463/1-listnothing-in-foldleft/27652729#27652729)

Comment: It won't help, but thanks. BTW, should your `def makeFoldSignal...` be a case class instead of function?

Comment: 1) you've probably messed up types with your (_, DateTime) - your `foldFun` should return `U` (`f: (U, T) => U`)which is `List[T]` but you return `U.head._1` 2) I used factory here be cause you can't have case class with two parameter lists (at least second one won't became `val` automatically and won't have `copy` etc.)

Comment: You're right, I truly messed up typed. I think I should consider to refactor my FoldSignal function.